# wget Recursive Download Issue

Tags: json, linux, recursion, gitlab, wget

I am having an issue where the wget tool is not recursively downloading all JSON files in all directories and sub-directories in a GitLab repository.

Command to write file paths to JSON

```
wget -r --no-parent -l inf -A json -nH --header="PRIVATE-TOKEN:$GITLAB_TOKEN_API_RW" -O document_list.json ${UPSTREAM_PROJECT_INFO}/${DOCUMENT_TREE_URL}/
```

`cat` output of JSON file

```
[{"id":"73e623804a849e7da015625cbcb075a332d793cf","name":"index-name","type":"tree","path":"documents/index-name","mode":"040000"},
{"id":"89e8d551d48d475936276c1baa266d0b921b79e6","name":"some-doc.json","type":"blob","path":"documents/some-doc.json","mode":"100644"},
{"id":"2e95832f6247932d4120fb8f4f87460305672b98","name":"doc.json","type":"blob","path":"documents/doc.json","mode":"100644"},
{"id":"995f6286542084fde7143c1c5d74b0cd2d75195c","name":"another-doc.json","type":"blob","path":"documents/another-doc.json","mode":"100644"},
{"id":"da493b905e4ee7396be676d2ad2053ebf3e43528","name":"my-doc.json","type":"blob","path":"documents/my-doc.json","mode":"100644"},
{"id":"c8d9d787b5db0cec426ca918d71f1f708821c0ad","name":"j-doc.json","type":"blob","path":"documents/j-doc.json","mode":"100644"}]
```

The file I am missing is located in the path `documents/index-name`; `index-name` is a sub-folder under documents in the repository. How can I traverse and successfully get that file in that directory? I'm assuming `wget` does not see `index-name` as `index-name/` (Traditional file system format).

Comment: Could a ~/.wgetrc be in the way? See https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Startup-File .

Comment: @Roadowl I believe it is an issue with wget not seeing the repository in the traditional file system format.